# SqlBulkCopy - Unexpected existing transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlbulkcopy

I am using `SqlBulkCopy` to insert large amount of data:

```
try
{
   using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
   {
      connection.Open();

      using (var tran = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
      {
          bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "table";

          bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("...", "...");                            

          using (var dataReader = new ObjectDataReader<MyObject>(data))
          {
              bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataReader);
          }

          tran.Commit();
          return true;
      }
   }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return false;
}
```

But I always get exception:

```
Unexpected existing transaction.
```

Why this exception happens?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> "Unexpected existing transaction" ... Why this exception happens?

This happens because using the `SqlBulkCopy` constructor without specifying a transaction will create its own transaction internally.

Avoid this by creating your transaction and then use it to create the `SqlBulkCopy`.  `SqlBulkCopy` can be created with the transaction that you want to use, like this:

```
connection.Open();
using (var tran = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
{
    using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, tran))
    {
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to use [the constructor that takes in the transaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wftd1yfz.aspx) so SqlBulkCopy will be aware of the transaction

```
connection.Open();

using (var tran = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
{
   using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, tran))
   {
       bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "table";

       bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("...", "...");                            

       using (var dataReader = new ObjectDataReader<MyObject>(data))
       {
          bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataReader);
       }

       tran.Commit();
       return true;

   }
}
```

Comment: is there a constructor that just takes connection and transaction?  I think you are missing BulkCopyOptions